# Using rails with security in mind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, security, jquery

I am currently developing a prototype for a chatbot.  Using devise and can-can I create a simple chat box that through the use of Jquery and Ajax send jsons requests to and from the website.  Since I did not use any of the rails helpers in my current build anyone can send a json object to this url (Lets call it mysite.com/message) and receive a response from the chatbot in Json.

I need help in getting rid of this vulnerability so that anyone regardless of whether or not they are logged in can send things to /message.  If there was a rails helper that generates something analagous to authenticity tokens that would be sufficient.  I've developed a few sites in rails but am still learning how to develop in the "Rails" way.

Edit:

The problem is that I do not want any logged in user to for example send a json object to /message when it is meant to be used only for the chatbox.  If I browse to the url then I can see the json response in my browser.

Comment: Please format your question as you would format your code (definately not in a spagheti manner)

Answer (score 0):

If those requests you are talking about are POST then you needed to disable authenticity tokens first!

If they are GET (I guess) then you may wish to alter those two methods in your `ApplicationController` (original versions here)

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb, line 174
def verify_authenticity_token
  unless verified_request?
    logger.warn "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" if logger
    handle_unverified_request
  end
end

# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb, line 186
def verified_request?
  !protect_against_forgery? || request.get? || request.head? ||
    form_authenticity_token == params[request_forgery_protection_token] ||
    form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']
end
```

especially in `verified_request?` change so it check also GET requests.

Comment: I'm sorry Michael I do not completely follow what you are talking about.  The AJAX requests I make are indeed POST.  The problem is that there is no authentication beyond being logged in.

Comment: Ok, i thought you use get requests. Forget that.

Answer (score 0):

Security is nasty and trouble some.

If your are looking for something simple and cheap, what about sending a cookie a random value with HTTP_ONLY set when the user logins in.

You keep a copy of the random value and compare when it comes back.

This is still subject to packet sniffing and man in the middle attacks, but it will protect from javascript attacks on the client page.  You have the username and stuff from the ajax and the cookie authentication that was issued when they signed on.

If security is really an issue, then you should start a Version 2, and get it done right from the start.  (As much as right can be, since it's a moving target...)

Comment: I'm just going to block everything but json requests for now